# No puedo traer los datos de la API.RAWG.IO

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

No sé por qué está función no me devuelve los datos de la api

ya probé el link y está bien

```
const getAllVideosGames = async () => {

    const apiVideogames = (
        await axios.get(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4be2ed928e1d42388d5f7aac8db2b987&page_size=100`)
    ).data;

    return [...apiVideogames];
};
```

Comment: Deberías estar obteniendo un error. La variable `apiVideogames` es un objeto, no es un iterable. Imagino que lo correcto debería ser `return apiVideogames.results;`

Answer (score 0):

### y por que no solo usas

```javascript
const getAllVideosGames = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4be2ed928e1d42388d5f7aac8db2b987&page_size=100`)
    return resp.data;
};
```

### y si quieres obtener el array de los resultados

```javascript
const getAllVideosGames = async () => {
    const resp = await axios.get(`https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=4be2ed928e1d42388d5f7aac8db2b987&page_size=100`)
    return resp.data.results;
};
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. La sección de respuestas es para propuestas _completas_ de solución, no para preguntas que requieran interacción. Para esto último, existe la sección de comentarios, que podrás dejar cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges).

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).